# Upload file data and variable ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to upload file data and a variable, when i submit a file it goes well. But if i append the variable there happens nothing. The thing what i see is the file data.

html:

```
<form id="articleData">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" readonly="readonly">
    Upload article csv: <input name="articleCsv[]" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="add">Add new items<br>
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="update">Update items

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my ajax request:

```
$("form#articleData").submit(function(event){
  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  var checked = $('input[name=item]:checked', '#articleData').val();
  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      formData.append('updateOrAdd',checked);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/spares/admin/importArticleCsv",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      alert(returndata);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

my php:

```
public function importArticleCsv(){
    $output[] = array();
    $response[] = "";

    $this->load->model('admin/csv');
    $url = $_FILES['articleCsv']['tmp_name'][0];
    $updateOrAdd = $_FILES;
    print_r($updateOrAdd);
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();

}
```

And the output of my print_r in the php code

```
Array
(
    [articleCsv] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Pmaster Inladen.csv
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => text/csv
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /Applications/AMPPS/tmp/php/php7VNPlg
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 111216
                )

        )

)
```

Where is my key (updateOrAdd) not in the array? I don't get it..

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: @MahaDev submit the output of var checked to my php.

Comment: you will get its value when it is checked. You will not get its key in case its unchecked. If you want its value in both forms then you must take another hidden input to keep its record when checked and unchecked